# Need to combine one column's value from many rows into a single row

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm try to create a report on Teradata security (DBC.ALLRIGHTS).  When a user has more than one permission, I would like to group those into one row.

These rows:

- DatabaseX   TableX  Dave   A
- DatabaseX   TableX  Dave   C
- DatabaseX   TableX  Dave   D
- DatabaseX   TableX  Dave   R

Would be combined like this:

- DatabaseX   TableX  Dave   A,C,D,R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [XMLAgg](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/wnWUYIhKCZ4erjv58Jv_fg/TmAqER9ykywV9ie8F~dR8w) for this:

```
select
databasename,
tablename,
username,
TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM (XMLAGG(TRIM(AccessRight)|| ',' ORDER BY AccessRight) 
 (VARCHAR(10000))))
from
dbc.allrights
group by 1,2,3
```

Comment: Please switch to `dbc.AllRightsV` :-)